# Ridding this query of Hash Match Join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following query that takes around 26 rows to return 8700 rows of data.

```
SELECT
  R.ClientReferralID,
  R.ClientID,
  C.FirstName,
  C.LastName,
  C.FullName,
  dbo.fnGetLocalDate(R.ReferralDate) as ReferralDate,
  RT.ReferralTypeName,
  R.ReferralTypeOther,
  RT2.ReferredToName,
  R.ReferredToOther,
  R.ReferredByID,
  U.FullName as ReferredBy,
  TS.TimeSpentName,
  R.Notes,
  L.ReferralLocationID,
  L.ReferralLocationName as Location,
  R.ReferralLetterSentID,
  R.ReferralLetterOnFileID,
  dbo.fnGetLocalDate(R.DateCreated) as DateCreated,
  U2.FullName as UserCreated,
  dbo.fnGetLocalDate(R.DateModified) as DateModified,
  U3.FullName as UserModified
 FROM
  ClientReferral R
 INNER JOIN Client C on
  R.ClientID = C.ClientID
 INNER JOIN LookUp.ReferralType RT on 
  R.ReferralTypeID = RT.ReferralTypeID
 INNER JOIN LookUp.ReferredTo RT2 on
  R.ReferredToID = RT2.ReferredToID
 INNER JOIN UserAccount U on
  R.ReferredByID = U.UserAccountID
 INNER JOIN LookUp.TimeSpent TS on
  R.TimeSpentID = TS.TimeSpentID
 INNER JOIN LookUp.ReferralLocation L on 
  R.ReferralLocationID = L.ReferralLocationID
 INNER JOIN UserAccount U2 on 
  R.UserCreated = U2.UserAccountID
 LEFT JOIN UserAccount U3 on 
  R.UserModified = U3.UserAccountID
 WHERE
  (R.ReferralDate >= @StartDate or @StartDate is null) and
  (R.ReferralDate <= @EndDate or @EndDate is null)
 ORDER BY 
  R.DateCreated DESC
```

The execution plan can be viewed here:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1A5ji7tf

I see the most costly operation is 65% on a Hash Match Join. I was expecting the following index to improve that but no:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Name] ON [dbo].[ClientReferral]
(
    [ClientID] ASC
)
```

Anyone see off hand what I can do here? Please let me know if some sample data is needed.

Comment: 1) try to disable idx used in `Client` scan 2) try to remove `OR` parts from `WHERE` clause, take another look at execution plan.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by ridding this query of hash match join?

Comment: @IvanStarostin - no difference with this.

Comment: Is it still using disabled index? What do you mean "no difference"? Do you have index on `ReferralDate`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin , execution plan stays the same along with execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index

```
ClientReferral ReferralDate
```

Or

```
ClientReferral ReferralDate, ClientID   
ClientReferral ClientID, ReferralDate
```

Comment: Unfortnately, no difference to the execution plan or the time it takes to run.

Answer (score 0):

First change

WHERE (R.ReferralDate >= @StartDate or @StartDate is null) and (R.ReferralDate <= @EndDate or @EndDate is null)

To

```
WHERE R.ReferralDate BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate,CAST(0 AS datetime2)) AND ISNULL(@EndDate,CAST(999999 AS datetime2))
```

After that create an index on

```
ClientReferral(ReferralDate, ClientID, ReferralTypeID, ReferredToID, ReferredByID, TmeSpentID, ReferralLocationID, UserCreated, UserModified, DateCreated, DateModified) INCLUDE(ClientReferralID, ReferralTypeOther, ReferredToOther, Notes, ReferralLetterSentID, ReferralLetterOnFileID)
```

Also show the code for

```
fnGetLocalDate
```

Comment: Is not always faster but worth a try